# Ravendb Live projections produces null values (Ravendb Lucene, Multimap, Live projections)

Tags: lucene, ravendb, multimap

Firstly, i am sorry for my english and i will be very happy if i can tell my problem very simply.

I spend so much time to solve multimap index and live projection problem. I read too much on stackoverflow, google, ayende blog etc... However couldn't solve my problem.

**What i want:**
   I have an app and want a twitter like search which is the twitter search box searches from multiple sources, such as from twit content, user names and hashtags. While i get result, i want to apply transform on results and shape index result into FullSearchResult model. Also i want to find that where the result is found. In the post, in user or in tag?

**The problem :**
   i have 3 type of docs (Post, User, Tag) and multimap index. When i create my multimap index with TransformResults i get all my results with null values. (I query my docs with multimap index by full text search).

**My Docs**

```
public class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public long SqlDbId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string ContentAsHtml { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public DenormalizedUser User { get; set; }

    public DenormalizedTagCollection Tags { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public long SqlDbId { get; set; }

    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public DenormalizedUser TagInserterDenormalizedUser { get; set; }

    public bool IsSystemTag { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class FullSearchIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<FullSearchResult>
{
    public FullSearchIndex()
    {
        AddMap<Post>(posts => from post in posts
                              let tags = post.Tags
                              where post.Status == Status.Active
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = post.User != null ? post.User.Id.ToString() : (string)null,
                                  PostId = post.Id,
                                  TagIds = tags != null ? tags.Select(tag => tag.Id).ToArray() : new string[0],
                                  SearchQuery = new object[] 
                                  {                                      
                                      post.Title,
                                      post.Content,
                                      post.Tags != null ? tags.Select(x => x.TagName).ToArray() : new string[0]
                                  },
                                  Source = SearchResultSource.ResultIsFromPost
                              });

        AddMap<User>(users => from user in users
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = user.Id,
                                  PostId = (string)null,
                                  TagIds = new string[0],
                                  SearchQuery = new object[] 
                                  {                                      
                                      user.Name,
                                      user.Surname
                                  },
                                  Source = SearchResultSource.ResultIsFromUser
                              });

        AddMap<Tag>(tags => from tag in tags
                            where tag.Status == Status.Active
                            select new
                            {
                                UserId = (string)null,
                                PostId = (string)null,
                                TagIds = new string[] { tag.Id },
                                SearchQuery = new object[] 
                                {
                                    tag.TagName
                                },
                                Source = SearchResultSource.ResultIsFromTag
                            });

        Index(searchResult => searchResult.SearchQuery, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

        TransformResults = (clientSideDatabase, results) =>
                                from result in results
                                let post = clientSideDatabase.Load<Post>(result.PostId)
                                let tags = clientSideDatabase.Load<Tag>(result.TagIds)
                                let user = clientSideDatabase.Load<User>(result.UserId)
                                select new
                                {
                                    PostId = post != null ? post.Id : (string)null,
                                    PostTitle = post != null ? post.Title : (string)null,
                                    PostContent = post != null ? post.Content : (string)null,
                                    PostTags = tags != null ? tags.Select(x => x.TagName).ToArray() : (string[])null,

                                    UserId = user != null ? user.Id : (string)null,
                                    UserName = user != null ? user.Name : (string)null,
                                    UserSurname = user != null ? user.Surname : (string)null,
                                    UserEmail = user != null ? user.Email : (string)null,
                                    UserMobileNumber = user != null ? user.MobileNumber : (string)null
                                };
    }
}
```

When i query using multimap index and lucene search i have 4 results. However, all values are null

```
query = "Tag50";
session.Query<FullSearchResult, FullSearchIndex>()
                        .Search(resultItem => resultItem.SearchQuery, query)
                        .As<FullSearchResultViewModel>()
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Also, i see my index results projected as i want (FullSearchResultViewModel) in ravend studio with having values all null

Answer (score 0):

Nkaya,
You assumed that the input of the TransformResults is the output of the Maps, but that isn't the case.
The input to TransformResults are the actual *documents*. The output of the maps is used to generate the index for searching ,not to shape how the input to the transform results looks like.

Comment: Because i use AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<FullSearchResult> generic type, my transform function accepts IEnumerable<FullSearchResult> type. Should i change the output of the map functions? If output of map functions change, how can i achive my goal? (find results from diffrent type of docs and detect any result where came from). Acctually, i tried to do same think as in this video 
'Complex Searching - RavenDB's Stag Party!' at the link 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_profilepage&v=B9WWg6uDMDs . In this video output shape of the map functions goes the input of the transform